# Hypothesis needed to show that $\lim \inf a_n \leq \lim \sup a_n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I came across this exercise :
For all sequence $(a_n)_ {n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of element in $\mathbb{R}$, establish the following inequality:
$$\lim_{n \to  +\infty} \inf a_n \leq \lim_{n \to  +\infty} \sup a_n$$

This is how is the resolution begins :
Let $\alpha$ be a reel number such that :
$$ \alpha < \lim_{n \to  +\infty} \inf a_n = \sup_{m}[\inf_{n\geq m}a_n] $$

Are we okay to say that this $\alpha$ is not always existing, e.g. take the sequence $b_n$ defined by :
$$ b_n = \begin{cases}
 2& \text{ if n is even}\\
 (-n)& \text{ if n is odd} 
\end{cases}$$
here the lim inf is equal to - infinity, so there's no way such an $\alpha$ exists right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\liminf_n a_n = -\infty$ then it is obvious that $\liminf_n a_n \le \limsup_n a_n$. I think the solution is assume the latter case, i.e $\liminf_n a_n > -\infty$

Comment: ahh sure, thank you very much!

Comment: It's a flaw in the redaction of the proof - it should contain a sentence along the lines of @ThànhNguyễn 's comment to say "let us now assume liminf > -infinity"